# bash: while - do stops after a while

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

It seems that it is a silly question but I can not see why my bash script behaves strangely.

I have a simple bash script which monitors a server and checks whether it is running or not.

The script works fine but it exists after around 30 sec. Then I start the script again, it is looping a little bit and exits again.

The server is continuously running, it is not stopped so I do not understand why my loop exit after a while.

```
#!/bin/bash
export ZOOKEEPER_HOST=localhost
export ZOOKEEPER_PORT=2181
export KAFKA_HOME=/home/.../server/kafka/kafka_2.11-2.0.0

# *********************************************************
# **    STOP: Kafka                                      **
# *********************************************************
stop-kafka() {
    echo "-> Stopping Kafka server..."
    #${KAFKA_HOME}/bin/kafka-server-stop.sh &
    while echo dump | nc ${ZOOKEEPER_HOST} ${ZOOKEEPER_PORT} | grep brokers
    do
        echo "Kafka server is still running..."
        sleep 1
    done
}

stop-kafka

exit 0
```

**This is the output of the first lines of my script on the console:**

```
xxx@hp:~/workspace/xxx/xxx$ ./test-run.sh 
-> Stopping Kafka server...
    /brokers/ids/0
Kafka server is still running...
    /brokers/ids/0
Kafka server is still running...
    /brokers/ids/0
Kafka server is still running...
```

**And the last lines before my script exits:**

```
Kafka server is still running...
    /brokers/ids/0
Kafka server is still running...
    /brokers/ids/0
Kafka server is still running...
    /brokers/ids/0
Kafka server is still running...
    /brokers/ids/0
Kafka server is still running...
    /brokers/ids/0
Kafka server is still running...
xxx@hp:~/workspace/xxx/xxx$
```

**--> UPDATE <--**

I modified my script as per suggestion of @shellter.

```
stop-kafka() {
    echo "-> Stopping Kafka server..."
    #${KAFKA_HOME}/bin/kafka-server-stop.sh &
    #while echo dump | nc ${ZOOKEEPER_HOST} ${ZOOKEEPER_PORT} | grep brokers
    while true
    do
        echo "Kafka server is still running..."
        echo dump | nc ${ZOOKEEPER_HOST} ${ZOOKEEPER_PORT}
        sleep 1
    done
}
```

I started it with this command: `./test-run.sh > test-run.log`

**Log file:**

```
...
Kafka server is still running...
SessionTracker dump:
Session Sets (3):
0 expire at Thu Jan 01 02:22:48 CET 1970:
0 expire at Thu Jan 01 02:22:51 CET 1970:
1 expire at Thu Jan 01 02:22:54 CET 1970:
    0x10000491a850000
ephemeral nodes dump:
Sessions with Ephemerals (1):
0x10000491a850000:
    /controller
    /brokers/ids/0
Kafka server is still running...  <-- missing content after this line
Kafka server is still running...
SessionTracker dump:
Session Sets (3):
0 expire at Thu Jan 01 02:22:48 CET 1970:
0 expire at Thu Jan 01 02:22:51 CET 1970:
1 expire at Thu Jan 01 02:22:54 CET 1970:
    0x10000491a850000
ephemeral nodes dump:
Sessions with Ephemerals (1):
0x10000491a850000:
    /controller
    /brokers/ids/0
...
```

After some loop, as you can see "payload" content is missing.
Is that a bug in `nc`?

Could you please suggest me another level of indirection?

Comment: `grep` didn’t find what it was looking for, so it failed, so the loop stopped. Not sure what’s so strange about that.

Comment: Is that means the official kafka monitoring tool provides not consistent output?

Comment: it's more likely that there is something wrong with `nc` which is notoriously problematic for this sort of situation. To confirm this, try running `echo dump|nc ${ZOOKEEPER_HOST} ${ZOOKEEPER_PORT} ` from the cmd-line and watch that output. Doesn't `kafka` have an html admin function that you can parse the output from? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: your assumption was correct. It seems `nc` is buggy. Could you please check my update?

Comment: See http://www.makedatauseful.com/web-console-for-kafka-messaging-system/ . I was thinking that you could do `curl -o - http://${ZOOKEEPER_HOST}:${ZOOKEEPER_PORT}/#/zookeepers | grep ...` to track your status. BUT, before you `while` loop, you issued a `shutdown` command. I would expect the software to stop working, and that once the remote program dies, not to get anymore feedback. So this is a case, IMO, that `nc` is working as designed. I'm available for consulting work so good luck! ;-)

Comment: Use `nc -v` to get nc's thoughts on the matter.

Comment: I was not able to use curl so finally I use the following condition: `while ps axu | grep [^]]zookeeper.properties > /dev/null 2>&1`